# Using BeautifulSoup to print specific information that has a <div> tag

Tags: python-2.7, printing, beautifulsoup

I'm still new to using BeautifulSoup to scrape information from a website. For this piece of code I'm specifically trying to grab this value and others like it and display it back to me the user in a more condensed easy to read display. The below is a screenshot i took with the highlighted div and class i am trying to parse:

[image]

This is the code I'm using:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
a =("http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=39.32196712788175&lon=-82.10190859830237&site=all&smap=1#.VQM_kOGGP7l")
website = urllib2.urlopen(a)
html = website.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
x = soup.find_all("div",{"class": "point-forecast-icons-low"})
print x
```

However once it runs it returns this "[]" I get no errors but nothing happens. What I thought at first was maybe it couldn't find anything inside the `<div>` that I told it to search for but usually I would get back a none from the code saying nothing was found. So what i believe to be going on now with my code is maybe since it is a  that its not opening the div up to pull the other content from inside it, but that is just my best guess at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `[]` because  `point-forecast-icons-low` class is not an attribute of the `div` rather it's an attribute of the `p` tag. Try this instead.

```
x = soup.find_all("p", attrs={"class": "point-forecast-icons-low"})
```

Comment: thank you that works i didnt know about that because it was nested inside a div so i thought it might not pick it out. however when i run it this way and print x i get the attribute point-.... then the value i wanted is there a way to discloude that from the output

Comment: i did not understand the new problem clearly. you may give some example and expected outcome. and  consider accepting the answer as it solves your issue.